# "A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column" with Id change

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

**Situation**

I have searched for the answer to this extensively (on SO and elsewhere) and I am aware that there are many questions on SO by this same title.

I had a table mapping and model that were working. Then the schema was changed (I do not have direct control of the DB) such that a new Primary Key was introduced and the old Primary Key became the Foreign Key to another table. ***I believe this is the heart of the problem as no other entities seem to have issues***

**Mapping**

Here is the method that maps my entity (called from OnModelCreating)

```
private static void MapThing(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<Thing>().ToTable("ThingTable");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Thing>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Thing>().Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("NewId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Thing>().Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Thing>().Property(p => p.FileName).HasColumnName("ColumnWhosNameChanged");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Thing>().HasRequired(p => p.MetaDataOnThing);

 }
```

The old PK of the table is now defined as a property on the model and it is the same name as the column (the reason it is not defined in the mapping above).

**Model**

Here is the Model (I have applied names that I hope will make it more clear what has changed):

```
public class Thing
{
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //This used to be the PK, its names (Property AND Column) have not changed
    public int OldId { get; set; }

    //The column name for FileName changed to something else
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    //Unchanged
    public byte[] Document { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    //Navigation Property
    public ThingMetaData MetaDataOnThing { get; set; }
}
```

**Integration test**

I removed a lot of structure to, hopefully, make it clear..the test is pretty straight forward

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ThenThingWillBePersisted()
    {
        var thing = new Thing()
        {
            OldId = metaDataObject.Id,
            Document = new byte[] { 42 },
            FileName = "foo.jpg",
            ContentType = "image/jpeg"
        };

        context.Things.Add(thing);

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This test produces the error "A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column:'NewId'" and the inner exception points to the NewId as being the issue. It does so on the SaveChanges() call.

Admittedly, I have a lot more experience with nHibernate than I do with Entity Framework but I am pretty sure my mappings and model are setup properly.

Has anyone seen this issue and how did you solve it?